# Rails - I18n: How do I find out translation path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with "resources" which I want to translate. I defined the translation in `xx.yml`:

```
xx:
  activerecord:
    models: 
      user:
        email: "xx"
```

And also tried "one" and "other" for label "email". But I still have the problem, either encounter:

```
I18n::InvalidPluralizationData (translation data {:email=>"xxx"} can not be used with :count => 1):
  i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n/backend/pluralization.rb:35:in `pluralize'
  i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:40:in `translate'
  i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n.rb:158:in `block in translate'
  i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n.rb:154:in `catch'
  i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n.rb:154:in `translate'
  activemodel (4.2.5) lib/active_model/naming.rb:188:in `human'
  activemodel (4.2.5) lib/active_model/errors.rb:437:in `generate_message'
  activemodel (4.2.5) lib/active_model/errors.rb:449:in `normalize_message'
  activemodel (4.2.5) lib/active_model/errors.rb:300:in `add'
  ...
```

```

or the translation doesn't hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to translate `email` attribute on user model. In that case you need:

```
xx:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "xx"
```

`models` keys are used to translate the model name, not its attributes.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy way of debugging active record i18n integration. The easiest way is by navigating to the source code and check there which translation it is looking for. The main reason it is not that simple is that internally it is creating a huge list of default values for translation. In your case it would be even more drastic as it is in completely different part of the code (as error is raised when generating name of your class rather than name of the attribute).

Comment: One way you can try debug it is to monkey patch I18n backend lookup method to print translation key and then calls previous implementation.

Comment: Any news on this one?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who gets here and wants to know easier way to figure out why rails not finds your defined translation.

To see in what paths rails are looking for translations, just add in gemfile:

```
gem 'i18n-debug', group: :development
```

Result will be in console like:

```
[i18n-debug] en.attributes.event_date => nil
```

Ref. https://github.com/fphilipe/i18n-debug